# Cannot find module 'sane/src/common'

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm just trying to run expo start then this error show me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCp2s.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Install sane and the error should be gone:-

```
npm install --save sane
```

or yarn

```
yarn add sane
```